# curvature in $\mathbb{R}^2$, osculating circle

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $f(x,y) = (x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2 - R^2$, and let $\gamma\colon(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}^2$ be a smooth curve, and $\gamma'(0)\neq 0$. I need to proof, that $C( (x_0, y_0), R$ is the osculating circle of $\gamma$ at $\gamma(0)$ iff

$f(\gamma(0)) = \frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}f(\gamma(t)) = \frac{d^2}{dt^2}|_{t=0}f(\gamma(t)) = 0$.

I have shown, that $<\gamma'(0), \gamma(0) - (x_0,y_0)> = 0$, but here I got stuck. Does anyone can help me with this?

EDIT: OK, I have shown, that $<(x_0, y_0) - \gamma(0), \gamma''(0)> = <\gamma'(0), \gamma'(0)>$, so I can take parametrization of $\gamma$, say $\gamma(s)$, that $||\gamma'(s)|| = 1$ for every $s$ in some $(a', b')$. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Taylor series:

$$ f(\gamma(t)) = f(\gamma(0)) + t \cdot \frac{d}{dt} \bigg|_{t=0}f(\gamma(t)) + \frac{1}{2}t^2 \cdot \frac{d^2}{dt^2} \bigg|_{t=0}f(\gamma(t)) + \dots $$

the Osculating circle is the one that agrees to $\gamma$ to second order... so all 3 terms must be zero.